# login with facebook android using realm node server

Tags: android, facebook, realm

#### I got this error:

> INVALID_PARAMETERS(601) "Your request parameters did not validate" upon login

#### here is my snippet code below,

```
SyncCredentials credentials = SyncCredentials.facebook(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
SyncUser.loginAsync(credentials, Api.AUTH_URL, LoginActivity.this);
```

Comment: What is returned in loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken() ?

Comment: string sir. that is
EAAbpj5fxiZBoBAOIFOZASesusfnOk8GIPCNXPuYqq5VNhuPYj3i7Tv23IXs5QYt9YZCZBZAfiL7ZCZADGSpx0NzE0uzruKhyZBx2e3NjMOTQyorredZABoRod38svTWT6nLMbEudTApEp5LfTBQiZC2uqR1Ik2acD7nmYmJAJJX5J7xCHJcaZBytiilZCEUQRDf..........

Comment: Hmm, that looks like a valid token. Is the facebook provider enabled on the server. You can find it under the `providers` section in the `configuration.yml` file?

Comment: I have already verified that token in graph api explorer.

wow in order to work with this it needs to uncomment the facebook provider. Thanks sir!